# Can't upload or see DEPLOY button getting highlighted - can't upload artifact .tar .tgz

Tags: repository, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

Artifactory Version: **EnterpriseX** license **7.15.3**

I see I have valid access to deploy artifacts in all the repositories where I'm trying to upload an artifact using Artifactory UI.

I go to the repository, see, under effective permissions, that my userid is listed with all permissions checked-in including upto **Manage** level.

When I try to upload a small .docx/.tar/.tgz file, it works fine.

When I'm trying to upload a large .tgz file **10+GB (in size)** (to be used in an **air-gapped** environment tar ball), then I'm not seeing the DEPLOY button highlighted so that I can click on it. It's still kind of greyed out (Greenish), see picture. It seems like after you select a file to upload, it does an animation of `1%--->reaching--->100%` and then after some time, shows you 2 check boxes for deploying as a deploy bundle and if you want to use a user-defined Layout format, but with the 10+GB tar file, when it reaches 100%, I don't see these 2 check-boxes in UI showing up and also the DEPLOY Green button is not highlighted so that I can click on it. I see a RED circle with a cross (which indicates, something is still not ready). Why it's even showing me 100% then for pre-upload/processing then?

Am I missing anything? I have already fixed the file size limit that I was facing for 100MB default file size limit in Artifactory repo.

[image]

**PS**: Related post when trying at command line level gives me 502 Bad Gateway and 403 errors: [Artifactory Curl -X PUT large file - 502 Bad Gateway The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server / 403 Bad props auth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298774/artifactory-curl-x-put-large-file-502-bad-gateway-the-proxy-server-received-a)

Comment: To confirm issues at the Artifactory level, we should first test out using the localhost, try to access Artifactory using IP and port, and try to deploy. Next if this fails a simple test to upload the artifact using the REST API as curl -u myUser:password -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/my/new/artifact/directory/file.txt" -T Desktop/myNewFile.txt use the localhost here. If REST API works, check if there are any errors or warnings in browsers console log which would help.

Comment: @MuhammedKashif for that I have raised this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298774/artifactory-curl-x-put-large-file-502-bad-gateway-the-proxy-server-received-a which gives me 502 Bad gateway or 403 depending upon file sizes using the same access key

Comment: Same issue happened to me for very large files. After progress was 100%, wait for a few minutes for the Deploy button to come to life.