# Artifactory Curl -X PUT large file - 502 Bad Gateway The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server / 403 Bad props auth token

Tags: api, curl, https, artifactory

Artifactory version:
**EnterpriseX license 7.15.3 rev 71503900**

I have admin level access on the target repository. I'm trying to upload an artifact which is close to 10GB long (air-gapped .tgz) file. I'm getting the following error.

When I try to upload the file using Artifactory UI (clicking Deploy button on the target repo), It  kicks me out back to login screen, while the upload says 100% complete but check-box/options for deploying artifact as "bundle artifact" or as per user defined "Layout" is not showing up, Deploy button at the bottom of that pop-up window is also grayed out.

Tried curl using Access Key as per documentation here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API but it gives me an error mesg after a very long time (12-13+ hours) about **502 Bad Gateway**.

I also tried using **-x ""** option to bypass proxy or prefixed the same command with `no_proxy="10.20.30.40" curl ....` but getting the same error. Tried -u user:pass, gives same error. Artifactory settings/DB configuration has been changed to allow for more connections and longer time allotted before timeout but still getting the same error.

PS: Notice that `0` under 258M in the 2nd line, i.e. line under **We are completely uploaded and fine** that tells me, nothing is getting uploaded.

```
$ curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:akfljkljkALDJALKDALKJDALKDJLASJDLAKDJALKDJALKDJALKDJALKDJALJKDLKAJFLANCMNLLgoEjcfZ-c7v58FmyaAUsJ8c0gFV6VVHp2WpvYbU7IftRyzirHEmsGJ3MRL0eZqCkyZYI_pkrcgXb3H2QcQ6RxDpbY2UYgX5AKQlrLhtb644wlBtK1VelsJ90d-6TPrr59ss-igGDhS-HUpSMAYMBl9cXQtT5hAR8Q" -X PUT "https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/AlphaPipeline-PRJ-ProjectABCPipeline-Production-Local/Pipeline-release-3.0.0.tgz" -T Pipeline-release-3.0.0.tgz -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 10.20.30.40...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to artifactory.company.com (10.20.30.40) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/tools/installed/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [76 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4146 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ABCDE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Denver; L=Centennial; O=Spotair Technologies; CN=artifactory.company.com
*  start date: Feb 24 20:54:47 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 24 20:54:46 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "artifactory.company.com" matched cert's "artifactory.company.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> PUT /artifactory/AlphaPipeline-PRJ-ProjectABCPipeline-Production-Local/Pipeline-release-3.0.0.tgz HTTP/1.1
> Host: artifactory.company.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> X-JFrog-Art-Api:akfljkljkALDJALKDALKJDALKDJLASJDLAKDJALKDJALKDJALKDJALKDJALJKDLKAJFLANCMNLLgoEjcfZ-c7v58FmyaAUsJ8c0gFV6VVHp2WpvYbU7IftRyzirHEmsGJ3MRL0eZqCkyZYI_pkrcgXb3H2QcQ6RxDpbY2UYgX5AKQlrLhtb644wlBtK1VelsJ90d-6TPrr59ss-igGDhS-HUpSMAYMBl9cXQtT5hAR8Q
> Content-Length: 11629208547
> Expect: 100-continue
>
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [5 bytes data]
 99 10.8G    0     0   99 10.7G      0   357M  0:00:31  0:00:30  0:00:01  258M* We are completely uploaded and fine
100 10.8G    0     0  100 10.8G      0   239k 13:11:33 13:11:33 --:--:--     0{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Date: Wed, 07 Jul 2021 18:55:33 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
< Content-Length: 232
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
{ [232 bytes data]
100 10.8G    0   232  100 10.8G      0   239k 13:11:33 13:11:33 --:--:--    54<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DPRJ HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Gateway</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>

* Connection #0 to host artifactory.company.com left intact
```

Another odd/annoying thing: If I use the same API Access Key on a small file (like few KBs) then I instantly hit the following **403 Bad props auth token** error. If I pass another file (**ex:** > 2MB) without changing anything in the command, it gives me the above 502 Bad Gateway error.

```
{ [824 bytes data]
100  2576  100   824  100  1752    675   1437  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  2113{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 403,
    "message" : "Bad props auth token: apiKey=my_long_apiAccessKeyHere."
  } ]
}
```

**PS**: Related post when using Artifactory GUI to upload the file.
[Artifactory - Can't upload or see DEPLOY button getting highlighted - can't upload artifact .tar .tgz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089204/artifactory-cant-upload-or-see-deploy-button-getting-highlighted-cant-uplo)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is the API key being used, I see this in the header,

> "X-JFrog-Art-Api:akfljkljkALDJALKDALKJDALKDJLASJDLAKDJALKDJALKDJALKDJALKDJALJKDLKAJFLANCMNLLgoEjcfZ-c7v58FmyaAUsJ8c0gFV6VVHp2WpvYbU7IftRyzirHEmsGJ3MRL0eZqCkyZYI_pkrcgXb3H2QcQ6RxDpbY2UYgX5AKQlrLhtb644wlBtK1VelsJ90d-6TPrr59ss-igGDhS-HUpSMAYMBl9cXQtT5hAR8Q"

From where did you generated the API key? As a test, can you use the credentials as -u :.
Also, generate the API key from the profile page and use that in the header.

Comment: Access key was generated for the user under profile and the above one is masked. I tried `curl` command with `-u user:myPass`, and various other options `-v` or -`--insecure...` and all gives me the same error mesg.